# How do I setup an Out of Office reminder in Outlook 2016 for a POP3 account?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016, out-of-office

I use Office 365 (2016), but do not have Exchange. I use POP3 emails exclusively via my business account with 1 and 1. Outlook doesn't have the typical option to setup OoO Reminders underneath the "File" menu. Help?

Comment: Awesome guys! Thanks for the reference to the existing question. Though we do the best to find what we're looking for here, sometimes it's a bit difficult to find the exact items. Y'all rawk!